# Doctrine DQL injection in ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, sql-injection, dql

I wonder, is there any way to make a DQL injection after ORDER BY clause? I know it's possible in SQL but I'm digging in documentation and Doctrine source code and cannot find any usable DQL use case.

For example, let's say we have following query

```
SELECT partial company.{id} FROM App\Entity\Company company ORDER BY company.id [DQL_INJECTION]
```

We can do something like this:

```
SELECT partial company.{id} FROM App\Entity\Company company ORDER BY company.id ASC, SUM(1) DESC
```

and the query will be valid and executed. But is there any way in DQL how we can extend the injection to inject full DQL query?

Comment: `UNION` follows `ORDER BY`. I don't use DQL, does it support `UNION`?

Comment: Nope, unions are not supported in DQL

Comment: Could you post an example of what it would look like with a full DQL query? Intuitively I would suggest using the QueryBuilder if you want to dynamically change queries, but I am not sure I get what you want to do in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking (for example) something like this but it should works: SELECT partial company.{id} FROM App\Entity\Company company ORDER BY company.id ASC, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM App\Entity\Company) DESC